# C++ how to make this as a volatile pointer inside constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I know I can add volatile keyword at the end of member function declaration to make this pointer as volatile but how to do it inside constructor ?

```
class A {
    void method() volatile; // inside method this is volatile pointer.
    A() {;} // How to make this as volatile pointer here.
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering under what circumstance volatile would be used in a constructor anyway. The object would need to be accessible to multiple threads for it to actually be useful

Comment: You cannot qualify constructors, because constructors aren't chosen by overload resolution on an object instance, because no object instance exists at the time where a constructor is called.

Comment: I'd like to note that `volatile` is almost never what you want - its semantics are hopelessly underspecified and it *does not* make anything thread safe. In most cases you probably want to reach for `std::atomic` instead.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make any sence in marking `this` as volatile, because value of `this` pointer is constant for any given object and can't change in no circumstances.